# Tooltip on Mobile devices (screen readers) without Javascript for a Wikimedia Commons SVG?

Tags: html, svg, tooltip

Below is a MWE of a most simple SVG with a simple title tooltip.

This title tooltip works fine on all Desktop browsers, but it does not on Mobile browsers (i.e. screen readers).

My question is simple: what is the easiest work-around to have tooltips display on screen readers, but WITHOUT Javascript (end-purpose is SVGs in Wikimedia Commons, where Javascript and other scripts are disabled).

**MWE of a SVG with a tooltip**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyVgJm

```
<title>This is a tooltip.</title>
```

This [website](https://www.24a11y.com/2017/the-trials-and-tribulations-of-the-title-attribute/) describes one method (see this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/scottohara/full/XVmdeb/)) where:

> "screen readers will announce the title as the accessible name for the
>   element in the code example".

```
<img src="my-image.jpg" title="The 3 little pigs build their houses">
```

But in this work-around which uses an image for something it is not designed to ... there seems to be no way to "toggle" (activate and DE-activate certain tooltips) and also no useful way to determine the exact location of the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

At first **[the title element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title)** in your example is wrong - **[the rect element is a basic SVG shape element and not a container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect)**. It can not have a title element.

At second some user agents may display the title element as a tooltip, but **[they do not have to display it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title)**.

If you want to have in all browsers a tooltip, then put your SVG in an HTML element like this:

```html
<b title="This is a tooltip">
    <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:blue">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
    </svg>
</b>
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this work on mobile devices as well (without capability to hover)?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen, this will work on mobile devices as well, but I do not understand what you mean with capability to hover in this case. Just check it.

Comment: Use any mobile device (with screen-only input, i.e. no mouse that is able to hover). Your code does not produce a tooltip that is shown on such mobile devices. I will up your answer +1 for the neat explanation about the correct use of the title element though, thank you.